# Getting './~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js' on ng build

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli for a MEAN stack application. It was working fine till yesterday, but today I am getting,

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js
8:11-74 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

on ng build.
And if i still proceed and run the application i get,

```
Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function
    at Object.260 (main.bundle.js:913)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:53)
    at Object.142 (main.bundle.js:11)
```

error on,

```
var User = __webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_mongoose__["model"])("User", UserSchema);
```

in main bundle.
My ts file where this code is,

```
export const User: Model<IUser> = model<IUser>("User", UserSchema);
```

I searched on net and tried many things but had no luck.
Also some posts are suggesting to run web pack,but this was working till yesterday where I had no web pack.

I also hardcoded the mongoose's version value by removing caret from pacakge.json, had no luck again.

Comment: You cannot use mongoose models in a browser based environment. Schema is allowed but no other functionality. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html

Comment: @NeilLunn the same code was working till yesterday. I just deleted node_modules and did a fresh 'npm install' after which this problem started.

Comment: Then since yesterday you picked up anything referencing a "model" into your build. The reason it does not work is because it is linked to dependencies compiled from C code. Cannot run in the browser.

Comment: @NeilLunn I added an new field in my schema with Enum as refrence type. I undid changes but still getting the same error.

Comment: @NeilLunn : you were right as soon as I created a different class for model it worked. Prior to this I was using the schema as a model in my angular app, as soon as I changed this it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a different typescript class for entity model that is to be used on UI(angular 2) side.

Earlier was using the schema class as model in my UI too, hence was getting this error.